# Ruby to convert nested array field to nested JSON objects

Tags: arrays, json, ruby, nested, logstash

I'm using ELK Stack Logstash and this is the format of the "target" data field that I need to convert now:

```
{
    "target": [
        "Sector1 - Subsector1",
        "Sector2 - Subsector2"
    ]
}
```

The desired JSON Output format that I need:

```
{
    "target": [{
        "Sector": "Sector1",
        "Subsector": "Subsector1"
    }, {
        "Sector": "Sector2",
        "Subsector": "Subsector2"
    }]
}
```

I've done some research and found out that the Logstash Ruby filter is able to perform the conversion, however I am not proficient in Ruby so if any pros here can help with the code it will be very much appreciated!

Comment: If above is ruby hash 'h' with all contents as a string, You can get required format by, `h['target'] = [h['target'].inject({}) { |m, i| m[i.split(' - ')[0]] = i.split(' - ')[1]; m }]`

Comment: @ray: If the above is a Ruby hash, your code won't work - you'd need `h[:target]`, not `h['target']`. :)

Comment: @Amadan I mentioned in comment as taking everything in string because if target is symbol, you cannot write like `'target':`, have to use `target:`. I provided solution for string using `'target' =>`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming input is JSON:

```
require 'json'

json = <<-EOF
{
    "target": [
        "Sector1 - Subsector1",
        "Sector2 - Subsector2"
    ]
}
EOF


data = JSON.parse(json)
data['target'].map! { |line|
  line.split(' - ').map { |str| [str[/^.*(?=\d+$)/], str] }.to_h
}
json = JSON.dump(data)
```

`map!` will replace `target` in-place; for each element, split by dashes, extract the key from each part by leaving out the numbers at the end of the part, and make a hash out of the collection of `[key, part]` pairs.

EDIT: If input is not JSON, but a Ruby `Hash` (already in `data` variable), then change `data["target"]` to `data[:target]`.

Comment: Are you sure this works on the input data? I think you did it backwards, your input data is the OP desired output.

Comment: @lacostenycoder: It works on the input data, if you take the natural assumption that both of the parallel structures are JSON, given that OP specifically said the second one is JSON. I see you and ray assumed the first one is Ruby (even though there are no hints one way or another). You both (EDIT: and iGian now as well) also assumed there will only ever be one dash in the input, which I do not (though, to be fair, that's all that is visible in OP's example, again, no hints one way or another).

Comment: fair enough, however in your answer perhaps you could have given example of how your input data needs to be defined as ruby with a `.json` on it. Considering the OP is a ruby noob, some explanation couldn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

This approach takes your example input data and defines it as a ruby hash, then modifies the data, then formats it back to json. Also the style I've used here is intended to be more readable for a ruby newbie.

```
require 'json'

data = {
    "target": [
        "Sector1 - Subsector1",
        "Sector2 - Subsector2"
    ]
}

data[:target] = [
  data[:target].inject({}) do |str, index|
    str[index.split(' - ')[0]] = index.split(' - ')[1]
    str
  end
]

json = data.to_json
puts json
#=>{"target":[{"Sector1":"Subsector1","Sector2":"Subsector2"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other option:

```
require 'json'

data.transform_values { |v| v.map { |e| {Sector: e.split(" - ").first, Subsector: e.split(" - ").last } } }.to_json

#=> {"target":[{"Sector":"Sector1","Subsector":"Subsector1"},{"Sector":"Sector2","Subsector":"Subsector2"}]}
```

Comment: I have to use the Logstash Ruby filter plugin that has its own syntax format: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-ruby.html. Your answer looks promising, any chance you can modify your answer to fit this plugin's syntax?

Comment: I don't know logstash at all. This is just my guess: maybe you can pass a hash to the fiter and get the json as output? In that case, just try remove `.to_json` and pass the resulting hash. No need `require 'json'`.